# No Form data after POST request via Ajax (Symfony)

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I'm using this code to call action via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/calculate"
});
```

And I'm trying to get form data by this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), new Entity());

if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->bindRequest($request);
    $data = $form->getData();
}
```

But the form is always emtpy. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: you forgot to define `data` in ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You are not passing any parameters with `$.ajax()`.

Comment: also I would say that if you want to output this form then you should you success in ajax

Comment: You're right. I just added `data: $("form").serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding data to ajax call solved this problem:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "{{ url('priceBlock') }}",
    data: $("form").serialize()
});
```